# Tick range of negative tick - Uniswap v3

Tags: solidity, uniswap, solidity-0.8.x, uniswapv3

I am looking for a formula to calculate the tick range for a negative tick.

```
Ex1: 
  tick: -15
  tickSpacing: 10
  range: [-20, -10)

Ex2:
  tick: -20
  tickSpacing: 10
  range: [-20, -10)
```

I was trying this formula

```
tickLower = tick / tickSpacing * tickSpacing
tickUpper = tickLower + tickSpacing
```

But this not working in the case of -15, it gives [-10, 0), which is not including -20

```
tickUpper = tick / tickSpacing * tickSpacing
tickLower = tickLower - tickSpacing
```

But this is not giving the right answer for -20, it give [-30, -20), which is not including -20

Someone knows a formula which works in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solidity, you need to add a conditional statement to implement this correctly:

```
tickLower = tick / tickSpacing * tickSpacing;
if (tick < 0 && tick % tickSpacing != 0) tickLower -= tickSpacing;
tickUpper = tickLower + tickSpacing;
```

The Uniswap source code itself [uses this pattern](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/TickBitmap.sol#L49).

**Explanation:** when dividing a negative number, some programming languages round the result up, some round it down. This is related to whether the `%` operator [computes the modulo or the remainder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1907723/2435820). In all sensible languages, the following invariant holds `x == x / k * k + x % k`.

- In languages like Python where `%` computes the modulo of the
  arguments, integer division must always round down for the invariant to hold.
- In languages like C and Solidity the remainder of `%` always has the   same sign as the dividend `x`, so the division `/` must round up for   the invariant to hold.

As a result, this code correctly works in Python, but not in other languages:

```
tickLower = tick // tickSpacing * tickSpacing
tickUpper = tickLower + tickSpacing
```